# django-admin --version displays error in virtual environment

Tags: django, windows, django-admin, command-line-interface, virtual-environment

After installing Django version 1.9 in a virtual environment using the following command in Windows:

```
django-admin --version
```

I receive a long error, ending with:

```
File "C:\Users\DELL\env\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 11, in <module>
    from collections import Counter, Iterator, Mapping, OrderedDict
ImportError: cannot import name 'Iterator' from 'collections' (C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\collections\__init__.py)
```

Python is installed, and the virtual environment was activated.

Django was installed using `pip install django==1.9`

What should I do to run the command `django-admin --version`?

Comment: What's in line 11 of your `query.py`, which is initiating the error?

Comment: it is a long error to one line of command, error msg is too big to post here. 
Problem is that I am unable to access django-admin in virtual environment via cmd prompt.
PS: I am a beginner

Comment: What happens if you try [`django-admin version`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/django-admin/#determining-the-version)?

Comment: displays same error

Answer (score 0):

Django 1.9 requires Python 2.7, 3.4, or 3.5..make sure you have installed python version from one of these..
(I have copied the answer that I got)

Answer (score 0):

You are using a very old version of Django and, as a result, your Python is incompatible with it. Django is trying to import `Iterator` from a Python module, but it was moved long ago from `collections` to `collections.abc` and that is why it gives you the `ImportError`.

You can either upgrade you Django to the current version or change your Python to below version 3.3